# Show loader until the content completely renders

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-loading-skeleton

Show Skeleton until the images are fully rendered

I am having a problem that i cannot fix and until now i am completely stuck.
I am redering a few images on a page in a React application using Redux. My problem is that while i am waiting for the images to load i am showing a Skeleton.
However the Skeleton stops showing the moment the data is received and the loading is set to false.
I prefer not to use J Query.
How can i set the loading state to false only after the images are fully rendered.

Help would be highly appreciated

Comment: How would jquery help here anyway? Can you post the relevant code or a reproduction of some sort please. Impossible to say based on a description of what's going on

Comment: https://www.javascriptstuff.com/detect-image-load/